# Submit via Ajax Unique PHP Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Alright, heres the scoop. I have a form that searches database by input => title

Form works great, returns every movie made by title...
Like so:

```
The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring
The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King
The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers
The Lord of the Rings
The Hunt for Gollum
```

Each movie has a unique ID and each title is a form with name="$ID". I need to be able to submit the form with its unique id to the processor.php to pull the rest of the movie info.

So if each form has a unique name eg; name="501" name="502" and so on...

How would I capture that within AJAX?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $('#status').load('processor.php', { 'mid': $('input[name="UNIQUE_INPUT_NAME"]').val()});                       
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

The above ajax returns info on name="502" but how can I pass a unique name="" to ajax to pull the right info?

I think I need to be able to pass a PHP Variable to ajax?

Answer (score 0):

If each `<form>` has its name set to the movie ID then:

```
$('#status').load('processor.php', { mid : this.name });
```

The form name will be present in `this.name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var curName = $(this).attr('name');
$('#status').load('processor.php', { 'mid': curName});
```

Comment: You would think this would work but its not. hitting submit does nothing... not even in firebug

Comment: you might want to use post to submit data to the server.

`$('form').submit(function(){
  var curName = $(this).attr('name');
  $.post('script.php', { 'mid': curName}).success(function(response) { $('#status').append(response); });                      
        return false;
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery serialize method get to pass all the movie details to the ajax page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('form').submit(function(){
     var vals = $('formid').serialize(); 
      $('#status').load('processor.php?'+vals);                       
     return false;
   });
 });
</script>
```